# Mega menu in OOTB navigation bar

Tags: navigation

How can i make the style of the OOTB navigation bar like the mega menu style. There are articles on the net, but they use a List as the data source of the menu. But i want the OOTB navigation bar behave like a mega menu? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It will take a lot of time changing SP2010 navigationbar dropdown behaviour and css modifications.
Alternatively I can recommend [Archetonomys solution](http://www.archetonomy.com/)

Comment: thanks for your concern but i am looking for a free solution

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is a really old question, but it showed up when I was reviewing some information for a blog post on achieving a mega menu using the ootb navigation.

http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2013/03/how-to-achieve-a-mega-menu-using-out-of-the-box-navigation-in-sharepoint-2013-and-jquery/

Hopefully it helps out anyone who comes across this in future.

Paul.